# 'tail -f' for a specific amount of time

Tags: linux, tail

I need to run `tail -f` against a log file, but only for specific amount of time, for example 20 seconds, and then exit. What would be an elegant way to achieve this?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

With GNU timeout:

```
timeout 20 tail -f /path/to/file
```

Comment: If the timeout is larger than typical file rotation you might also want to use the follow=name (-F) option of GNU Tail.

Answer (score 20):

For completeness sake, without `timeout`, you can do this:

```
#!/bin/sh
tail -f /var/log/syslog &
me=$!
trap "kill $me" INT TERM HUP QUIT EXIT
sleep 20
```

The `trap` line ensures that when the script or parent shell is terminated (we reach end of script (EXIT), Ctrl-C (INT), sending a SIGTERM via `kill`, logging out of the shell (HUP), etc) then the `tail` is killed.

Comment: I'd need to test it, but I'm pretty sure the last line is not necessary as the shell should trap when exiting?

Comment: Or you could trap `EXIT` along with the others.

Comment: @OlivierDulac Only if he trapped `EXIT`, I believe.

Comment: Good points all. On testing, a final `kill` is needed else tail is orphaned off on script exit. Additionally I've modified the script to make trap catch exit and remove the last kill, which looks a more elegant solution. A further shortening could be done by removing the `me=$!` line and referencing `$!` in the trap kill directly, but I leave this as an exercise for the consumer :-)